# Remotely create Subversion repositories and manage user accounts

Tags: svn

Do you know any web application for creating and managing subversion repositories/accounts? I know there are plenty of Subversion web-based clients but none of them seems to handle server-side settings.

Answer (score 1):

[trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) can work with accounts I believe. If you use the Account Managers Plugin and use the same login method as SVN.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though there's a Webmin plugin available for repos, but not accounts:

http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?search=subversion